# Custom form validation: JSON

Tags: html, json, angularjs, validation

I am trying to validate a **JSON** input with Angular's FormControl.

The normal way to do it, for example an e-mail, would be:

```
<form name="form">
   <textarea ng-model="data.email" type="email" name="email"></textarea>
</form>
```

There are several built in "Tokens" (email, number, date,...) in [Angular's FormControl](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/form.FormController).

- Is it possible to build my own **JSON** "Token"?  `< ... type="json">`
- If not, is there an easier way to do this validation? I don't necessarily need AngularJS for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can build it for json. But it will not be `type="json"`. It will be `type="text" validate-json` and then you can add a custom directive.

```
app.directive('validateJson', function(){
   return {
      restrict: 'A',
      require: 'ngModel',
      link: function(s,e,a,c) {
         c.$parsers.puch(function(value){
             if(value is json) {
                 c.$setValidity('json', true);
             } else {
                 c.$setValidity('json', false);
             }
         });
      }
   }
})
```

Of course there nothing like `value is json` in javascript. I do not actually know how to validate string as a valid JSON. But this is a concept.

Now you can use `ngMessages` to report error

```
<form name="form">
   <textarea ng-model="data.email" type="text" name="json_field" validate-json></textarea>
   <div ng-messages="form.json_field.$error">
      <div ng-message="json">Field is not valid JSON.</div>
   </div>
</form>
```